# Share weights between two dense layers in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, theano

I have a code as follows. What I want to do is to share the same weights in two dense layers.

The equation for op1 and op2 layer will be like that

`op1 = w1y1 + w2y2 + w3y3 + w4y4 + w5y5 + b1`

`op2 = w1z1 + w2z2 + w3z3 + w4z4 + w5z5 + b1`

here w1 to w5 weights are shared between op1 and op2 layer inputs which are (y1 to y5) and (z1 to z5) respectively.

```
ip_shape1 = Input(shape=(5,))
ip_shape2 = Input(shape=(5,))

op1 = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", kernel_initializer = "ones")(ip_shape1)
op2 = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", kernel_initializer = "ones")(ip_shape2)

merge_layer = concatenate([op1, op2])
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merge_layer)

model = Model(inputs=[ip_shape1, ip_shape2], outputs=predictions)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the biases must be separate?

Comment: @DanielMöller I think if I am going to share weights then biases will also be same. Question updated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This uses the same layer for both sides. (Weighs and bias are shared)

```
ip_shape1 = Input(shape=(5,))
ip_shape2 = Input(shape=(5,))

dense = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", kernel_initializer = "ones")

op1 = dense(ip_shape1)
op2 = dense(ip_shape2)

merge_layer = Concatenate()([op1, op2])
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merge_layer)

model = Model(inputs=[ip_shape1, ip_shape2], outputs=predictions)
```

Comment: it's also described here: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers

Comment: What if you want the weights to be trainable in one network but not in the other, but you want the 2nd one to be updated whenever the 1st one is trained?

Comment: Add a `Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))` at the end of side 2.