# Is it possible to create a model in Keras Functional API without an input layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, functional-api

I would like to create a model consisting of 2 convolutional, one flatten, and one dense layer in Keras. This would be a model with shared weights, so without any predefined input layer.

It is possible to do using the sequential way:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(20,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200,activation=tf.nn.relu))
```

However, using the Functional API, produces a TypeError:

```
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu)
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(20,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu)(model2)
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(model2)
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200,activation=tf.nn.relu)(model2)
```

Error :

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fb060598100>
```

Is it impossible to do this way, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cannot  add an input layer?

Comment: It is not possible in either API (Sequential or Functional), it makes no sense to have a neural network without an input layer, why do you want to do such a sthing?

Comment: I would like to have shared weights. So 2 separate input layers, then several shared convolutional layers, then 2 separated out layers. It is certainly possible to do with just one shared layer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875127/share-weights-between-two-dense-layers-in-keras), but I haven't seen an example on how to do it with more. But if I try to link more of them together, it gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keras sequential api is designed to be easier to use, and as a result is less flexible than the functional api. The benefit of this is that an input 'layer' shape can be inferred automatically by whatever shape of the data you pass to it. The downside is that this easier to use model is simplified, and so you can't do things like using multiple inputs.

From the [keras](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) docs:

> A Sequential model is not appropriate when:
>
> - Your model has multiple inputs or multiple outputs
> - Any of your layers has multiple inputs or multiple outputs
> - You need to do layer sharing
> - You want non-linear topology (e.g. a residual connection, a
>   multi-branch model)

The functional api is designed to be more flexible i.e. multiple inputs, and so it doesn't make any sort of automatic inference for you, hence the error. You must explicitly pass an input layer in this case. For your use case, it might seem odd that it doesn't automatically infer the shape, however when you consider the wider use-case scenario it makes sense.

So the second scenario should be :

```
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,3,2)) # specified input layer
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu)(model2)
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(20,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu)(model2)
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(model2)
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200,activation=tf.nn.relu)(model2)
```

**Update**

If you want to create two separate models and join them together, you should use the functional API, and then due to it's constraints you must therefore use input layers. So you could do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, concatenate, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input1 = Input((10,3,2))
model1 = Dense(200,activation=tf.nn.relu)(input1)

input2 = Input((10,3,2))
model2 = Dense(200,activation=tf.nn.relu)(input2)

merged = concatenate([model1, model2])

merged = Conv2D(10,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu)(merged)
merged = Flatten()(merged)
merged = Dense(200,activation=tf.nn.relu)(merged)

model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=merged)
```

Above we have two separate inputs and then two Dense layers - you can build these separate lines however you want, and then to merge them together to pass them through a convolutional layer you need to use a `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` layer, and then you can continue the joint model from there. Wrapping the whole thing inside a Model object then allows you access training and inference methods like fit/predict etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how do I attach 2 input layers?
That is why I wanted to do without an input layer, to have a sequence of layers without input, then pass 2 separate input layers to the sequence, making 2 separate models with separate inputs, separate outputs, but shared convolutional layers.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this is still not what I wanted to achieve. I would like something like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875127/share-weights-between-two-dense-layers-in-keras), but with multiple shared layers (they call it dense in the linked question). I might ask another question because I asked X, but what I really need is Y.

Comment: I agree perhaps it's clearer to ask a separate question. If you think I answered your original question though I'd appreciate an 'accept' :)

Answer (score 0):

The linking in `keras` works by propagating `tensors` through the layers. So in your second example, at the beginning `model2` is an instance of a `keras.layers.Layer` and not a `tf.Tensor` that why you get the error.

[`Input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) creates a tensor which can then be used to link the layers. So if there is not a specific reason, you just add one:

```
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,3,2))
model2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(10,3,2,'valid',activation=tf.nn.relu)(model2)
```