# How to create a model with multiple shared layers in Keras Functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, functional-api

I would like to have a model with 2 inputs, several hidden layers with shared weights, then separate output layers.

I have seen this question and its accepted answer: [Share weights between two dense layers in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875127/share-weights-between-two-dense-layers-in-keras) . This is exactly what I would want to achieve, just with multiple shared dense layers.

Basically, this is what they do:
(I modified it a little to have 2 separate output layers)

```
ip_shape1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))
ip_shape2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))

dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="ones")

op1 = dense(ip_shape1)
op2 = dense(ip_shape2)

op1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(op1)
op2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(op2)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[ip_shape1, ip_shape2], outputs=[op1,op2])
```

I would like to do the same, just with 2 shared hidden layers:

```
ip_shape1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))
ip_shape2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))

dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="ones", input_shape=(5,))
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="ones")(dense)

op1 = dense(ip_shape1)
op2 = dense(ip_shape2)

op1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(op1)
op2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(op2)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[ip_shape1, ip_shape2], outputs=[op1,op2])
```

But when I try to do this, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f7286dc7c70>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs in the following line:

```
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="ones")(dense)
```

Essentially, you are calling the dense layer with `dense` (another Keras layer). Instead, the layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense` expects a tensor as input.

---

I presume that you want to compose two shared dense layers. This can be achieved as follows:

```
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="ones", input_shape=(5,))
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="ones")

op1 = dense_1(ip_shape1)
op1 = dense_2(op1)

op2 = dense_1(ip_shape2)
op2 = dense_2(op2)
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it, it works. Judging by the model summary, this is what I wanted to achieve.